# Stretching Images In ASP.NET

Tags: css, image, width

My image has a width of 1000px.
If i'm using style="width:800px" it works great but if I use Style="width:1500px". it doesn't stretch my image and leaves it at 1000px.

how do I make my picture stretch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is an HTML and css question (client side), not specifically an asp.net question, so the answer will apply regardless of the server-side technology.

If you want it to stretch, you need to set ***both*** the height and width explicitly.  If you specify one or the other, the browser automatically adjusts the one that's not specified to maintain proportions.

Comment: Yea but I don't want to change the height of the image. only the width

Comment: The fact remains that using css and javascript you can't stretch an image without specifically setting both height and width. You can manipulate it on the server and stretch that way, but not client-side. You didn't post in your question WHY you want to strecth the image so that limits our ability to offer alternatives. For example, if you want to use an image of a background and have it stretch to match the size of the container, you can use the tips listed here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/9279.htm

Comment: ohhhh I'll simply use corners as mention in your link! Thanks ^^